# JLabel with HTML containing "<" and ">" characters

Tags: java, html, swing, special-characters, jlabel

From time to time I use HTML in JLabels in Java Swing. Lastly I've came across something a little bit, for me, confusing...

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("<html>Label 1: 300 > 100 and 90 < 200 </html>");
        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("<html>Label 2: 300 &gt; 100 and 90 &lt; 200 </html>");
        JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("<html>Label 3: 300 \u003E 100 and 90 \u003C 200 </html>");
        frame.add(lbl1);
        frame.add(lbl2);
        frame.add(lbl3);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

[image: Output]

Could anyone explain me why in labels 1 and 3 I see `">"` character, **while `"<"` is not visible**? I assume, that `"<"` and `"u003C"` are interpreted in exactly the same way, and as a special HTML character cannot be correctly interpreted, but if yes, why `">"`, which is also a special character in HTML, is displayed?

Are `&lt` and `&gt` the only correct options?

Answer (score 2):

The JLabel implementation assumes a raw `<` was part of an invalid opening tag for an html element, and it drops it. You can use `&lt;` or `&#34;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Are &lt; and &gt; the only correct options?
```

As per knowledge you are right.These two are universal accepted.

`&lt;` means Less than .

`&gt;` means greater than.