# How to move the text to the next line in the JLabel without HTML?

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

In the JLabel to move the text to the next line I use *HTML*:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><b>Line<br/Next line</b></html>");
```

Is there a way to move the text to the next line *without using HTML*? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JLabel with HTML containing “<” and “>” characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412323/jlabel-with-html-containing-and-characters).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to move the text to the next line without using HTML?

Not really. Instead you must use other techniques, such as:

- Use multiple JLabels held in a GridLayout with 1 column
- Use a JTextArea, but configure it to look like a JLabel (one of my favorites)
- Or write text directly into the component via its `paintComponent(...)` method.

Comment: I need to display a symbol of **&lt** with XML - file and it does not appear in HTML.

Comment: @Tomas: I believe that there are common HTML solutions to that.

Comment: @Tomas: so your question is in effect [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better in the future that you tell us the **complete** overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than focusing excessively on how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments . But you answered my main questionю

Comment: @Tomas: possible duplicate link posted as comment to your main question. Again, next time, please provide all the pertinent details in the main question.

Comment: 1+ , `Use a JTextField...,` since the OP wants to wrap text to the next line you might want to use a JTextArea, since it supports wrapping.

Comment: @camickr: thanks for catching that. I actually meant to say `JTextArea` but farked up.

Comment: `...meant to say JTextArea...` - my fingers type something different than my brain is thinking all the time....

Comment: @camickr: it's worse with my mouth!!

Answer (score 1):

**There is no other way for JLabel.** You can use custom Swing component though.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the HTML way? You can simplify it like this:

```
String line1 = "...";
String line2 = "...";
String text = String.format("<html>%s<br/>%s</html>", line1, line1);
JLabel lbl = new JLabel(text);
```

Comment: I need to display a symbol of &lt with XML - file and it does not appear in HTML.

Comment: Do you mean the HTML entity `&lt;`? Which is "less than" character `<`.

Comment: Yes it is. I read this symbol with XML-file in JLabel. But he does not appear.